# Trouble finding proper regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to find any three digit numbers and only two mathematical operators which are plus and minus (+ or - ).

My attempt is:

> "(?=.*[0-9]{1,3})  (?=.*[+-])"

First parenthesis says, all numbers between 0-9, minimum 1 occurences and maximum 3. The other parenthesis says + and -.

I use this regex in a split but when I enter the string

> String str = "22 24 +"

-

> str.split("(?=.[0-9]{1,3}) (?=.[+-])")

the output is

> String [] outputArray = {22, 24 +}

Expected outcome:

> String [] outputArray = {22,24,+}

Which means that somehow, the plus did not get recognized..

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your expected input and output? Also, it looks like you're trying to solve infix/postfix operations. If yes and if you don't have any constraints, then consider using a stack instead of regex

Comment: That is true, I am trying to solve postfix operations. My expected outcome is {22,24,+}

Comment: you should rather first match the string for conditions and then split.

Comment: let say `(?=.[0-9]{1,3})` has maximum 3 digits but still you have in regex for operators, right!

Comment: I can't quite follow you. I have two parenthesis, one for numbers that have one to three digits. And one for operators.

Comment: Give this a try: `"\\s(?=.[0-9]{1,3}|[+-])"` :

Comment: With that expression I get the following: [22 24 +]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **split** your source string, then the proper regex is
e.g. `" +(?=\\d{1,3}|[+-])"`, meaning:

- A sequence of spaces (I added "+" to split also in the case of
  **multiple** spaces between tokens).
- A positive lookahead - either 1 to 3 digits or plus or minus.

Another possible approach is to **find all matches**.
Then the regex can be e.g. `"\\d{1,3}|[-+]"`, meaning:

- Alternative 1: A sequence of 1 to 3 digits.
- Alternative 2: Either a plus or a minus.

Below you have an example program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Simple{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "22  24  +";
    // Variant 1 - split
    String [] outArr = str.split(" +(?=\\d{1,3}|[+-])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outArr));
    // Variant 2 - find all matches
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}|[-+]").matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
      allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allMatches.toArray()));
  }
}
```

Both variants print `[22, 24, +]` - a list of findings.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to split using a pattern here.
You need to match and group. Here is what you are asking for:

```
final String str = "22 24 +";
final String pattern = "([0-9]{1,3}|[+-]{1})";

final List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);
while (m.find())
{
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allMatches.toArray()));
```

Comment: `final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);` What does that last part                          mean? `.matcher(str)` how can you just add it to the matcher object like that